# XMLHttpRequest: Double TCP SYN within a millisecond in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: xmlhttprequest, webserver, internet-explorer-9, embeddedwebserver

the XMLHttpRequest object causes two TCP SYN Packets when I try to send some POST data.
This happens in less than a millisecond.
I cannot reproduce this behavior in any other browser (tested with the latest Firefox and Google Chrome browser).

Even the 'asynch' Flag or timeout setting does not seem to change the situation.

The Problem is that when IE9 sends two SYN, they will be automatically ackowledged by the Server's TCP/IP Stack. But unfortunately IE9 then sends the Post data in the second stream, which means that the web server is already waiting for bytes on the first socket (causes a timeout).
This happens because we are talking about a single threaded web server that can handle one socket at once.

Any suggestions or ideas?

I would like to prevent IE9 from establishing two sockets at once.

This happens no matter if I use the Jquery ajax function or implement it by myself in java script.

Best Regards

Matthias

Comment: Isn't a "single-threaded web server" going to run into all sorts of problems in general?  Fascinating question however.

Comment: Not necessarily when we talk about embedded devices that have usually only a few clients at the same time. Not thousands like on a normal website. The requests will be handled within a short time period and the TCP/IP stack is able to queue requests until the backlog is full.

Comment: Well OK, yes that makes perfect sense :-)  I wish I could offer some insight, but this sort of thing is outside my range of experience. I would love to find out more however.

Comment: Sounds strange that a single _XMLHttpRequest_ would generate 2 tcp connections. Do you see the syn packets on a network trace, wireshark or similar? If the second connection sends the post data, what is the content of the first connection?

Comment: I see actually two SYN packets in Wireshark in less than a millisecond. Then according to the Source port I can see that IE9 sends the payload on the second tcp connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea, you could try adding a `Connection: close` header in all server responses to make sure the browser is starting a new tcp connection for every request.

Comment: The server already does this. But finally I came to some sort of workaround. When I add an HTTP connection header close on the client side: It seems to change the client sided TCP stack behavior that it does not send any more two syn packets. Anyway Problem is solved with connection close http header on both sides. If anyone had an explanation for it, I am still interested. Thanks for all your comments and answers.

Answer (score 1):

We are noticing the same thing via wireshark, IE9's own F12 debugger shows a single POST, but the packets coming out of the client IE9 machine shows two POSTS... and the server receives 2 as well which causes inconsistent problems for our app on the server side.

Version 9.0.8112.16421, update versions 9.0.3 (KB 2586448)

We had to enable the IE8 compatibility header to stop the double posts

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" /`>

It's very odd... doesn't happen with all our forms, almost like the JS compiler is coming to certain conclusions about how to execute the code in different contexts.

Good to know about the header close on the client side... that might be better for us long term... hopefully it will be resolved in IE9

Comment: I think this might be related to IE9's aggressive preconnection:  http://www.belshe.com/2011/02/10/the-era-of-browser-preconnect/

Comment: I added the IE8 meta tag last year to fix a different issue, then recently moved it to a different template that would cover the previous issue while letting my new page use IE9 mode for CSS3 rounded corners and such. Then, when the change was published, our customers started complaining of double-charges on their credit cards. Ugh, just when I thought I couldn't hate IE more...

Comment: I had a chance to revist this recently with WireShark and what i see is the client (IE9) performs a POST, then before the client has a chance to send the reply IE9 performs an abortive release (ACK+RST), closing the connection, then it resends the same POST again which looks like a double post on the server side.   For our app, the server already got the first POST and wasn't coded to handle this abortive scenario which only seems to be problematic with IE9.

Comment: The abortive release could be due to any number of things going on within IE, none of which you really have any control over on the server side.   Your application should be able to deal with this... but it is so out of character with how other browsers (and previous versions of IE) behave that i'm sure many people are having this problem and at a loss for how to deal with it. Though not specific to IE9, this paper was interesting in providing a discussion on the logic for abortive releases [http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~brecht/theses/Shukla-MMath.pdf] (search for "Internet Explorer").